# C++ check if string is space or null

Tags: c++, string

Basically I have string of whitespace `"                    "` or blocks of whitespace or `""` empty in some of the lines of the files and I would like to know if there is a function in C++ that checks this.

****note***:* As a side question, in C++ if I want to break a string down and check it for a pattern which library should I use? If I want to code it myself which basic functions should I know to manipulate string? Are there any good references?

Comment: A lot of the answers currently posted seem to be missing the clause "or blocks of whitespace". I think the idea is to find lines containing only zero *or more* whitespace, where the "or more" could be more than 1.

Comment: @SC: That part of the question is an (unnecessary, IMO) clarification added after most of the answers.  A "string" is already a sequence of characters, not restricted to just one.  But hey, I tried to provide an answer that accounted for that, and got lambasted by Alf for assuming the input is ASCII (which is a far more reasonable assumption than the one he's making, IMO).  So my answer will languish at the bottom forever.  That's ok, I don't need the rep.  I'm leaving it there in case Mark appreciates an answer that actually works.

Comment: @Ben: Sorry 'bout that, I didn't try to "lambast" you. It's just that a great many novices code up incorrect simple calls to `isspace` and family. So I think it is Very Important to correct the simplistic calls wherever they appear, so that people reading it can learn how to call these functions correctly (and what's the danger of not calling them directly).

Comment: @Alf: And I immediately acknowledged that you were right about the potential for passing a negative value and associated problems.  Most novices would probably benefit from being told that `isspace` is not guaranteed to work the way they expect on extended characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified an interpretation of characters > `0x7f`, I'm assuming ASCII (i.e. no high characters in the string).

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

// Returns false if the string contains any non-whitespace characters
// Returns false if the string contains any non-ASCII characters
bool is_only_ascii_whitespace( const std::string& str )
{
    auto it = str.begin();
    do {
        if (it == str.end()) return true;
    } while (*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f && std::isspace(*(it++)));
             // one of these conditions will be optimized away by the compiler,
             // which one depends on whether char is signed or not
    return false;
}
```

Comment: -1 generally incorrect call of `std::isspace`. argument needs to be casted to `unsigned char` (or equivalent expression). please fix.

Comment: @Alf: Casting to `unsigned char` wouldn't be correct either.  When you start supporting non-ASCII characters, you need to know an encoding, start thinking about multi-byte characters, etc.

Comment: @Alf: I fixed it to never pass negative numbers to `std::isspace`.  Do you think there's still a problem?

Comment: @Ben: yes, there's still a problem, namely failure to recognize as whitespace a value that is negative as `char`. That is, that the function can produce a false negative. Simply cast to `unsigned char` to fix it, for the default encoding (the actual argument is then implicitly promoted further up to `int`, but the total effect is not the same as a direct cast to `int`: you should cast to `unsigned char`).

Comment: @Alf: What part of "If it's not ASCII, you need to account for multi-byte characters" is unclear?  This function is written (and now documented) to work correctly on ASCII strings.  If the input isn't ASCII, the logic would be (1) encoding-dependent and (2) much more complicated.  A cast to `unsigned char` is not an appropriate fix.

Comment: @Alf: But here, I'll make it obvious that it tests for a string of ASCII whitespace characters, by putting ASCII in the function name.  Is that good?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, in itself. But consider the simpler and more efficient `is_sbcs_whitespace` function, utilizing the check `isspace( (unsigned char) ch )`, where the cast in practice generates no machine code at all. Since ASCII is a Single Byte Character Set any users needing this functionality for ASCII could then use your simpler & more efficient function, and also users with characters encoded as Latin-1 or Windows ANSI Western or other SBCS'es could then use is. So, while the new contract is good ... it can be *even better*. Well, unless you want to sell also a Latin-1 version, etc... ;-)

Comment: @Alf: I don't think so.  `isspace` will be correct for ASCII and exactly one unspecified SBCS.  If it works for Latin-1, then it doesn't work for ANSI.

Comment: @Ben: `isspace` isn't hardcoded that way. Its effect depends, as I recall, on the C library's locale. That locale can be selected by `setlocale`. And for that reason it's generally a good idea to call `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" )` at the start of the program. This changes the locale from the C locale (with pure ASCII) to whatever the natural user's locale is on the machine, e.g. one with Windows ANSI. Perhaps I should have mentioned that. I forgot, so, thanks for drilling down to that.

Comment: @Alf: And at some point in there, the extra locale handling becomes more expensive than a non-negativity check (if I really cared about performance, I'd tighten the upper and lower bounds to be strict on the set of ASCII whitespace characters, and then do lookup in a small table).  Then, there's the overload of `isspace` in `<locale>` for handling extended characters in a controlled way.

Comment: @Ben: I was not talking about any "extra" locale handling. Just that `isspace` isn't hardcoded the way that you apparently thought, and that an initial call to `setlocale` is a good idea to be able to use those C lib functions. The idea you have for improving performance is, AFAIK, how a typical `isspace` implementation works. PS: Latin-1 is a strict subset of Windows ANSI Western, and I don't think the latter adds any whitespace characters. That's irrelevant to our discussion, though, except that you inadvertently (most probably incorrectly?) used those two in your example. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf: Not sure, but I think most implementations of `isspace` does a table lookup for all characters, with no short-circuiting.  But what I was saying was that if I cared about performance, I'd use a single table without the locale-specific indirection.  And those two codepages -- I assumed that you'd mentioned two signficantly different codepages in your earlier comment.  My mistake.

Answer (score 7):

```
bool isWhitespace(std::string s){
    for(int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++){
        if(!std::isspace(s[index]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: use `std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(s[index]))` - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string str = ...;
if (str.empty() || str == " ") {
    // It's empty or a single space.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't account for multiple spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
 std::string mystr = "hello";

 if(mystr == " " || mystr == "")
   //do something
```

In breaking a string down, `std::stringstream` can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a nullstring "in some of the lines of the files".

But you can have an empty string, i.e. an empty line.

You can use e.g. `std::string.length`, or if you like C better, `strlen` function.

In order to check for whitespace, the `isspace` function is handy, but note that for `char` characters the argument should be casted to `unsigned char`, e.g., off the cuff,

```
bool isSpace( char c )
{
    typedef unsigned char UChar;
    return bool( ::isspace( UChar( c ) ) );
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: This doesn't handle strings at all, nevermind that a "string of whitespace (characters)" has arbitrary length (whitespace is uncountable).  And blindly casting to `unsigned char` is usually the wrong thing to do with non-ASCII strings.

Comment: @Ben: Positive, you have understood correctly that the function doesn't handle a string. It handles a `char`. You have failed to understand the purpose of the cast. It is not a good idea to fill in that void by an assumption of "blindly casting". This cast is necessary to avoid Undefined Behavior, in general. It exemplifies how to use this function & family correctly. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: You replace undefined behavior with probably wrong behavior.  e.g. most non-ASCII characters are represented in UTF-8 these days, and `::isspace` will do the wrong thing if you pass it a UTF-8 lead byte.

Comment: @Ben: Your argument, if correct, would apply to most of the C++ standard library's character handling... :-( Dealing with UTF-8 and other variable length encodings is much more difficult, because the standard library has a fixed size assumption. The function above is the most efficient and general function. As such it can be wrapped with any conditions you want, at the cost of efficiency. Going the other way, producing the efficient and most general function from a limited function, is in general *not possible*. In essence, you can't get rid of inefficiency once you add it in at bottom.

Comment: @Alf: AFAICT, all of the C++ standard library character handling is only specified for the basic character set, which means ASCII on all current platforms.  Handling of OEM characters > 0x7f is completely implementation-defined and non-portable.  C++ doesn't even specify what the range of valid values for a character is, (except that it definitely is a strict superset of 0-127)

Comment: @Ben: sorry, I don't believe you believe that yourself. You *must* be aware of the zillions of applications made using C++. Heh.

Comment: @Alf: I'm pretty sure that anyone using an extended character set who cares about correctness is using some NLS library (typically iconv) and not relying on C++ standard library string manipulation.

Comment: @Ben: tell that to Microsoft. :-)

Comment: @Alf: Microsoft provides [NLS in the Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646979.aspx), IIRC.  Unfortunately, UTF-8 is not among the supported codepages for nearly all these functions.

Comment: I got an unexplained downvote with regard to this topic today as well.  So it might be strategic voting.  Or someone who thinks they know something we don't, but is unwilling to share.

Answer (score -2):

If you want pattern checking use regexp.

Comment: ...which would be completely overkill for such a simple scenario like this. This answer is also lacking any detail.

Comment: he asked for "if I want to break a string down and check it for a pattern which library should I use"

Comment: As a "side question". Stack Overflow does not do "side questions". And "regexp" is not a library. It is a broad description of a wide range of Regular Expression engines, implemented by a wide range of libraries.