# C++ Strings - How can I implement this 'IsEmptyOrSpace(string)' method for wstring's?

Tags: c++, string, encoding

Okay, I searched StackOverflow on how to check if a string is empty or just whitespace. But, it only works with ANSI strings. How can I get it to work with a `wstring`?

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//! Checks if a string is empty or is whitespace.
bool IsEmptyOrSpace(const string& str) {
    string::const_iterator it = str.begin();

    do {
        if (it == str.end())
            return true;
    } while (*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f && isspace(*(it++)));
    // One of these conditions will be optimized away by the compiler.
    // Which one depends on whether the characters are signed or not.

    return false;
}
```

My first thought was to change `isspace(*(it++))` to `iswspace(*(it++))`, but the two conditions before that will only work with ASCII, right? Here is what I have so far on attempting to adapt the function to `wstring`'s:

```
bool IsEmptyOrSpaceW(const wstring& str) {
    String::const_iterator it = str.begin();

    do {
        if (it == str.end())
            return true;
    } while (*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f && iswspace(*(it++)));
    // One of these conditions will be optimized away by the compiler.
    // Which one depends on whether the characters are signed or not.

        // Do I need to change "*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f" to something else?

    return false;
}
```

Is my approach close to being correct? Either way, how can I implement a Unicode version of this `IsEmptyOrSpace()` function?

**EDIT:**
Okay, if you need to know why the `*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f` test is there, I cannot tell you, because I do not know. I got the code for the function from the answer to this question: [C++ check if string is space or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325483/c-check-if-string-is-space-or-null)
So let me start from scratch, how, in general, may I check if a `wstring` is EMPTY or just whitespace?

Comment: Why are you doing the `*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f`-test? It's hard to know how you want to generalize this to `wstring` when we don't know the why :)

Comment: A `std::wstring` cannot *ever* be "null". It can be empty, or it can contain only whitespace, but it does not have a "null" state. So you might want to rename the function :)

Comment: Okay guys, I'm not advanced at C++, so i don't know much about how strings work down to the bottom. @MagnusHoff I didn't write the `*it >= 0 && *it <= 0x7f` test, the author of the answer to this question did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325483/c-check-if-string-is-space-or-null

Comment: I have no idea why it is there, so forget the test, let me start from scratch: How can I check if a `wstring` is EMPTY or space?

Comment: @MagnusHoff Alright I edited the question to reference where I got the code and to clarify that I do not know what that check is for, but actually, I think `*it >= 0` checks for a `'\0'`, and `0x7f` is the ASCII code for the backspace control character.

Comment: @jalf Noted, edited to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the two conditions before that will only work with ASCII, right?

That's right. They make sure the value conforms to the precondition of `isspace`: the argument "must have the value of an `unsigned char` or EOF". Strictly speaking, you only need the `*it >= 0` check, which should be optimised out if `char` is unsigned; alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, you could convert the value to `unsigned`.

`iswspace` has no such precondition, so just remove those checks from the wide version:

```
bool IsEmptyOrSpaceW(const wstring& str) {
    wstring::const_iterator it = str.begin();

    do {
        if (it == str.end())
            return true;
    } while (iswspace(*(it++)));

    return false;
}
```

As a matter of style, there's no need to add a strange wart like `W` to indicate the parameter type, since you can just overload `IsEmptyOrSpace` with different parameter types.

Comment: Yes, I did that just for clarification it was a unicode version of the method. In reality, I have a `typedef basic_string<TCHAR> String;` and I use that as the parameter, and inside the function I just have pre-processors to determining which do-while-loop condition to check for based on whether UNICODE is defined. +1, great in-depth answer, thank you very much!

Comment: "Strictly speaking, you only need the *it >= 0 check" - alternatively you can (probably should) convert the value to `unsigned`: `isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(*(it++)))`. This allows for the theoretical possibility of a locale which has whitespace characters with negative values.

Comment: Where did you find that precondition for `isspace`? I've run into some problems with third-party code which passes in values of plain (implicitly signed) `char`'s, and I've been unable to find any official word on this precondition.

Comment: @SteveJessop +1 for a way to possibly avoid unwanted behavior. So I would need to write `while (*it <= 0x7f && static_cast<unsigned>(isspace(*(it++))));` for the ASCII version?

Comment: @jalf: I got it from the [Linux manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace). I don't have a copy of the C standard to hand at the moment, so I can't check whether that's an official precondition.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: There's no need for the `<= 0x7f` check at all. After the cast, the value will be in the correct range for `isspace`.

Comment: Ah I see, also I goofed on that last comment anyways, I put the static_cast around `isspace()` instead of around `*(it++)`. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @jalf: C99 standard, 7.4/1. My "lazy" reference is opengroup.org, though. It includes some Posix-specific stuff so you have to be careful, but for this example `isspace` it duplicates the generally-applicable text in the description of each of the functions it applies to. So it's a bit more user-friendly than the standard when all you care about is one function at a time.

Comment: And in C89 it's 4.3, in case the person you're telling off is a stickler for C++03 and hence professes not to care what C99 says :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsEmptyOrSpaceW(const wstring& str) {
  return str.length() == (size_t)std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), L' ');
}
```

or

```
// this code works for string and wstring
    template <typename CharType>
    bool IsEmptyOrSpace(const std::basic_string<CharType>& str)  {
      return str.length() == (size_t)std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), CharType(32));
    }
```

> Actually, there are other types of whitespace, such as tab characters,
>   and I'm not positive as to whether or not this code handles those
>   whitespace characters.

if we want to handle all those whitespace characters, we can find first symbol that isspace function returns false

```
template <typename CharType>
bool IsEmptyOrSpace(const std::basic_string<CharType>& str)  {
  return str.end() == std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
          std::not1(std::ptr_fun((int(*)(int))isspace)));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure as to how that would work until I test it, but at the moment that seems pretty clever and quick.

Comment: Actually, there are other types of whitespace, such as tab characters, and I'm not positive as to whether or not this code handles those whitespace characters.