# read empty undesirable string C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, getline

So I'm using the `map<string,int>` to associate a string with an integer value so that each int represents the number of times the string appears, and at the end I print each string and the percentage of times it appeared .

my code is that:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef pair<int,int> ii;

typedef vector<string> mc;

typedef vector<ii> vii;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int T ;

    cin>>T;

    while(T--){
        string s;
        map<string,int> m;
        int to=0;
        getline(cin,s);
        while(getline(cin,s)){
            if(m[s]==0){
                m[s]=1; 
            }
            else 
                m[s]++;
            to++;
        }
        for (map<string,int>::iterator i = m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
            cout<<i->first<<" ";
            printf("%0.4lf\n",(double)i->second/(double)(to-1) *100.0);
        }


    }



    return 0;
}
```

but for same reason the output is:

```
 3.4483
Ash 13.7931
Aspen 3.4483
Basswood 3.4483
Beech 3.4483
Black Walnut 3.4483
Cherry 3.4483
Cottonwood 3.4483
Cypress 3.4483
Gum 3.4483
Hackberry 3.4483
Hard Maple 3.4483
Hickory 3.4483
Pecan 3.4483
Poplan 3.4483
Red Alder 3.4483
Red Elm 3.4483
Red Oak 6.8966
Sassafras 3.4483
Soft Maple 3.4483
Sycamore 3.4483
White Oak 10.3448
Willow 3.4483
Yellow Birch 3.4483
```

for my input :

```
1

Red Alder
Ash
Aspen
Basswood
Ash
Beech
Yellow Birch
Ash
Cherry
Cottonwood
Ash
Cypress
Red Elm
Gum
Hackberry
White Oak
Hickory
Pecan
Hard Maple
White Oak
Soft Maple
Red Oak
Red Oak
White Oak
Poplan
Sassafras
Sycamore
Black Walnut
Willow
```

and it must be:

```
Ash 13.7931
Aspen 3.4483
Basswood 3.4483
Beech 3.4483
Black Walnut 3.4483
Cherry 3.4483
Cottonwood 3.4483
Cypress 3.4483
Gum 3.4483
Hackberry 3.4483
Hard Maple 3.4483
Hickory 3.4483
Pecan 3.4483
Poplan 3.4483
Red Alder 3.4483
Red Elm 3.4483
Red Oak 6.8966
Sassafras 3.4483
Soft Maple 3.4483
Sycamore 3.4483
White Oak 10.3448
Willow 3.4483
Yellow Birch 3.4483
```

I think I may have read somehow an empty line but I can't figure out how I made it , someone can tell me what I made wrong please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your while loop where you're reading in the file, you need to test for the line being empty or all white space, and skip it if it is.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly expected. Your input contains **two** header lines and you only skip one. The simplest solution would be to skip this line by using a second call to `getline()`.

By the way, please do not use competitive coding shortcut when pasting code in your question. (`#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and other cryptic typedefs)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the [string is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325533/329082).